# I keep getting 'Cannot destructure property 'title' of 'product' as it is undefined.' in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am working on a react project and trying to show more details on a product with `react-router` `useParams`, but I keep getting the error `'Cannot destructure property 'title' of 'product' as it is undefined`.

Here's the code for the single products

```
import React from "react";
import products from "../data2";
import { Link, useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const SingleProducts = () => {
  const { productId } = useParams();
  const product = products.find((productg) => productg.id === productId);
  const { title } = product;

  return (
    <section className="section product">
      <img />
      <h3>{title}</h3>
      <h3></h3>
      <Link to="/products">Back home</Link>
    </section>
  );
};

export default SingleProducts;
```

and here's for the product items

```
import React from 'react'
import { products } from '../data2'
import style from '../Styles/ProductItem.module.scss'
import StarRateIcon from '@mui/icons-material/StarRate';
import {Link} from "react-router-dom"

const ProductItem = () => {
  return (
    <div className={style.container}>
        {products.map((item)=>{
    return (
    <article key={item.id} className={style.product}>
        <h1>{item.title}</h1>
        <h1>{item.id}</h1>
        <div>
           <img src={item.images} />
        </div>

        <div>
            <p>{item.title}</p>
            <h4>${item.price}</h4>
            <p>{item.stock} items left</p>
            <div className={style.rating}>
                <p>{item.rating}</p>
                <StarRateIcon className={style.star}/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <Link to={`/products/${item.id}`}><button className={style.btn}>View more</button></Link>
        <div className={style.discount}>
            <p>- {item.discountPercentage} %</p>
        </div>
        </article>);
        })} 
    </div>
  )
}

export default ProductItem
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array.prototype.find` potentially returns `undefined` if no match is found. The component logic should handle this case and only attempt to access into defined objects. Add a check on the returned `product` value and conditionally render alternative UI.

You should also be aware that the route path params will ***always*** be a string type, so you'll want to ensure you are using a type-safe comparison in the `find` predicate function. Converting the value you are comparing against the path param to a string is sufficient.

Example:

```
const SingleProducts = () => {
  const { productId } = useParams();
  const product = products.find((productg) => String(productg.id) === productId);

  if (!product) {
    return "No matching product found.";
  }

  const { title } = product;

  return (
    <section className="section product">
      <img />
      <h3>{title}</h3>
      <h3></h3>
      <Link to="/products">Back home</Link>
    </section>
  );
};
```